# What page function occurs after event handling?

Tags: asp.net

This is probably a silly question. Let's say I have 20 event handlers that will go off after the postback. I want to open a connection to the database right before the events start, and then close it right after they end. Where would I put my open and close statements in my webform?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Events are raised after `Page_Load` event in the page's life cycle. So you could open it there and close it in `Page_PreRender`.

But actually i would suggest to avoid open connections at all. An open connection can not be reused. So you should always close connections as soon as possible where you've used it, best by using [`using-statement`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

Comment: This was my issue. I have never NOT used the using statement, but I don't want to open and close it for each event because I'm keeping track of the context between events, so I need to keep it until the end when I can save changes.

Comment: What means _keeping track of context_ here? How is it related to the connection? What events are we talking about, why are multiple events raised at all?

Comment: Well I have a (potential) change of anywhere from 1 textbox to 300+ textboxes. These changes correspond to the database. Originally I was just changing them individually on the textchanged event, but 300+ calls to the database just doesn't work. So I set it up to change all of them without accessing the database, THEN once they are all updated, call SaveChanges once.

Comment: Then you can use the `LoadComplete` event (or later events). Because at this point of the page's life cycle, **all the postback events were already processed, this is guaranteed** Therefore, you can use a `using` statement in the `LoadComplete` event to open a connection to the database **once** and call `SaveChanges`

Comment: So you want to tell me that up to 300 events are raised? Why don't you use one button to post back and save all afterwards in one update statement? Apart from that, you can use **one event handler for all textboxes**.

Comment: I mean all my textboxes call the same event. And I only have one button that causes a postback. The issue is I don't know how many have changed and I don't want to iterate through 300+ textboxes if only one has changed.

Comment: Then you might want to use a late stage in the page's lifecycle(f.e. `PreRender`) and save all detected changes. You could store them in a property(f.e. a `List<TextBox>`) that you fill from the `TextChanged` event handlers. Just an idea.

Comment: This is clearly a design problem. Even when you could think in a justification for what you are doing, I do not think your end users would feel comfortable having to scroll down the page in order to find the exact field they want to update. Well... Anyway. You could then have a private `List` on the page and populate it with the fields that were updated, then just use this list to call `SaveChanges`

Comment: Well unfortunately I don't get to decide the design :P
This was the solution I used, I never thought of putting it into a list. Solved every issue I could think of.

Answer (score 1):

You need to understand the [ASP.NET page life cycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472(v=vs.100).aspx)

The postback events occur between the `Load` and `LoacComplete` page's events, therefore if you want to guarantee that the connection is opened, you could open it in the `Load` (or before) event and close it in the `LoadComplete` event (or later)

However if an error occurs, probably the `LoadComplete` event won't be called.

It is a better approach to use a `using` statement to work with database connections:

```
using(var cn = new SqlConnection(".."))
{
   cn.open();
   // here your database code
}
```

As a quick view:

[image]